# How to change the iOS app icon in iTunes Connect when update the version?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, itunes, app-store-connect

I am trying to add a new version of an existing iOS app.

I successfully uploaded the binary and the screenshots.
My problem is I need to change the app icon.

When I change the app icon and click save button it displays a error message

"You must upload a large app icon." 
My icon image size is 1024 * 1024 and it's in png format.

Comment: Make sure that the image 72DPI as stated in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Comment: How to check the DPI..?

Comment: Open image preview, Go to Tools Menu -> Adjust size -> Resolution. Value of resolution is dpi

Comment: my image has the resolution of 200

Comment: @iBeginner your app icon contain rounded corners?

Comment: @Yasika the image is uploaded successfully but when I click the save button then only it displays the error...

Comment: @iBeginner plz use jpg image png with transparency is not allowed.

Comment: I tried with both but it shows the same error. this whole day I spend with this prob....

Comment: @Alex I the prob is with the Itunes Connect, Today they updated their web page...

Comment: @iBeginner but I still have same problem

Comment: @Alex See my below answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I done it. I reject my binary from the queue and then I uploaded a new binary also uploaded a new 1024 * 1024 size large icon and now my prob is solved.

Answer (score 1):

> For all images and icons, the PNG format is recommended. You should
>   avoid using interlaced PNGs.
>
> The standard bit depth for icons and images is 24 bits—that is, 8 bits
>   each for red,    green, and blue—plus an 8-bit alpha channel.
>
> You don’t need to constrain your palette to web-safe colors.

Comment: the image is uploaded successfully but when I click the save button then only it displays the error...

Answer (score 0):

Itunes connect was fixed this bug. Without rejecting binary I could change the app icon